# How to build WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

how to access to svn and build Identy server from sources?

The page http://docs.wso2.org/display/identity/Building+WSO2+Identity+Server+from+source is valid also for 3.2.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Identity Server on Linux from Source Distribution [[1]](http://docs.wso2.org/display/identity/Installing+Identity+Server+on+Linux+from+Source+Distribution) Guide.

When you extract the wso2is-3.2.3-src distribution execute mvn clean install from the root level OR if you need to build only 3.2.3 version go inside the /wso2is-3.2.0-src/patch-releases/ folder. 
There you will find separate directories for 3.2.1, 3.2.2 and 3.2.3, To build 3.2.3 version, start building from 3.2.3 patch releases pom.xml (mvn clean install from /wso2is-3.2.0-src/patch-releases/3.2.3/ directory).

Please note, 3.2.0 branch needs to be built with maven2.

FYI: To build current trunk, use maven3.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I would access to trunk and get the actual patches for passiveSTS login issue. there are info about this?

Comment: Hi, you can get a snapshot build from http://wso2.org/bamboo/browse/WSO2CARBON-PRODUCTS-69/artifact Please refer to IS build packs there.