# How to build WSO2 Repositery?

Tags: maven, maven-2, wso2, wso2-esb

Hi every one i am trying to build wso2-4.4.1 through maven-2.2.1 when i run "mvn clean install" command it  will run but it will give lot of error Unable to find resource repository(lot of repository name is there).can i add any other repository?.

if any one have some time please help me thanx....

Some error is given bellow...

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jvnet.hudson.svnkit:svnkit:jar:1.1.4-hudson-4' in repository oauth (http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jvnet.hudson.svnkit:svnkit:jar:1.1.4-hudson-4' in repository sonatype (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/openid4java)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.felix:felix-parent:pom:2.1' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache:apache:pom:9' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:maven-plugin:2.3.7' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'biz.aQute:bndlib:pom:1.50.0' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.bundlerepository:pom:1.6.6' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.osgi:org.osgi.core:pom:4.1.0' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.easymock:easymock:pom:2.4' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-core:pom:2.0.7' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven:pom:2.0.7' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:5' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-settings:pom:2.0.7' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-model:pom:2.0.7' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:pom:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:pom:1.0-beta-2' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-providers:pom:1.0-beta-2' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:pom:2.0.7' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:pom:1.0-beta-2' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:pom:1.0-beta-2' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jtidy:jtidy:pom:4aug2000r7-dev' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.geronimo.genesis:genesis:pom:1.4' in repository apache-incubator (http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository/) 

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config:pom:1.4' in repository apache-incubator (http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository/)
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.5.8' in repository jansi (http://jansi.fusesource.org/repo/release) 


[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.sonatype.gossip:gossip:pom:1.0' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-1.6:pom:1.2' in repository repository.dev.java.net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
```

Answer (score 2):

What are the errors you get? Some previous discussions might help you in this matter.

1. [What is the appropriate way to build WSO2 Carbon tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365363/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-build-wso2-carbon-tags/10413655#10413655)
2. [How to build WSO2 Identity Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332817/how-to-build-wso2-identity-server/10348460#10348460)

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: Hi, As mentioned in the above [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365363/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-build-wso2-carbon-tags/10413655#10413655, you need to build the trunk with maven 3

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell me the svn location you downloaded the code? which product you are going build?

If you are focusing 4.0.2 branch, Following are the build procedure to build carbon 4.0.2 branch. Please build it by using maven 3.

1. Checkout code base from [a],[b],[c].
2. Do a clean build from "orbit/tags/4.0.2/patch-releases/4.0.2/pom.xml"
3. Then build kernel module from "kernel/tags/4.0.2/patch-releases/4.0.2/pom.xml"
4. Finally build platform patch release pom "/platform/tags/4.0.2/patch-releases/4.0.2/pom.xml"

a. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/orbit/tags/4.0.2/

b. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.0.2/

c. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.2/

Comment: What is the purpose of each of the three code bases: orbit, kernel and platform?

Comment: Vivek :)   This is Rajneesh Gupta here :)